# Chrome plugin window image inverted

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, graphics, firebreath, windowless

We are working on a video player plugin with FireBreath. It has a windowless mode, and in Chrome on Windows it produces a very strange effect.

Whenever we try to paint in the `hdc` the pixels appear either in the right colour or inverted, depending of the value of the most significant bit in any of the 3 channels.

This means that in full colour depth on average half of the pixels appear inverted, while the other half is fine. It is the same both when displaying a video frame using `StretchDIBits()`, and when just filling with solid colours with `FillRect()`. The `SetStretchBltMode()` is set to `COLORONCOLOR`.

We could not find a solution so far, our temporary hack is to convert the colours to half the depth and set all the most significant bits to 1, but it's obviously a bad solution for the waste of CPU effort and losing half the colour depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Chrome has a weird bug that way.  The easiest fix is to set your background color to black behind the window; there is a [whole thread on this on the firebreath-dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebreath-dev/chrome$20background$20black/firebreath-dev/vMMleauNSKA/ZL5jIR2l2hUJ).

EDIT: bug might actually not be the right term, on reflection; it has an interesting implementation that way =]